# Facing error in using java method with

Tags: java, methods

My code is using two different classes:

```
package ashir1;

public class ahmed {

    public void function (String name){
        System.out.println("Hello" + name );
    }
}

//import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Scanner;
package ashir1;

class faisal{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ahmed ahmedobject = new ahmed();

        System.out.println("Type your name here");
        String name = (name);

        ahmedobject.function(name);
}   
    }
```

I am facing the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:
>
> at ashir1.faisal.main(faisal.java:8)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is that = String name = (name); ???

Comment: What does `string name = (name)` mean?

Comment: is this all in the same file? then move the `import` line to the top (as second line) and remove the duplicated `package` declaration below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only error I can see in your code is this:

```
String name = (name);
```

It makes absolutely no sense. I am pretty sure it was a typo, and I think you meant:

```
String name = input.nextLine();
```

By setting a variable equal to itself, the compiler is getting confused by your meaning.

Comment: If you found the solution worked, then mark the answer correct, as it will help other users. @fyzeeqa

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ahmed ahmedobject = new ahmed();
System.out.println("Type your name here");
String name = input.nextLine();
ahmedobject.function(name);
```